# Updating Existing migration in EF6

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework, i have already applied 23 migrations, now i have a migration at #14, which is a stored procedure and now i want to make updates to that stored procedure.

I am not sure how i shall edit the existing migration at #14, could anyone suggest best method to update the migration #14.

I tried `add-migration "[exact name of the migration at #14]"` but that does not edits that migration, rather creates new migration.

Is there any commands which would edit that migration and then i can make the edits to that migration.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't edit it. Migrations should be considered append-only. In the case of a stored procedure editing the existing migration would also introduce the problem that the schema at the time may not correspond to the schema that the stored procedure code expects.

You should add a new migration with an `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement updating the code.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, Appreciated